# Kerberos Authentication [Microsoft C++]

Tags: c++, visual-c++, kerberos

We have a app. In that app we are using NTLM for domain authentication using c++. But we decided to upgrade our app to use KERBEROS authentication for some productivity. As we all know, KERBEROS is more secure compare to NTLM. That's why we are decided to change that.

I don't know how to implement kerberos authentication using c++.
Here's the code snippet, that we are already using for authentication(NTLM).

```
ADsOpenObject(rootstring,username, password, dwReserved,IID_IADs, (void**)&pIadsSchema);
```

AdsOpenObject : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/adshlp/nf-adshlp-adsopenobject

Simply my need is, how to do a kerberos authentication using c++.

NOTE: The code should authenticate user available in the same domain as well as cross domain[machine that is not the part of the domain].

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: How does the app receive user credentials? Does it receive NTLM responses from client apps, or does it just ask the user for username & password and _internally_ verify that via NTLM? (Is it a web app or a desktop app?)

Comment: Thanks for replying, We only give username and password. And It's a webapp.

Comment: Yes it's just ask username and password, and internally proccessing via NTLM. I want to change that into kerberos.